# At what point of my input file is the subfig package loaded?

Tags: packages, subcaption, preamble

When trying to compile my report, I receive an error related to the `subcaption` package (which I load in my preamble):

> ! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
>   (subcaption) with the subfig package.

After some research, I found that the `subcaption` and `subfig` packages cannot be used at the same time. The problem is that I don't load `subfig` *explicitly* anywhere in my preamble. It must get loaded somehow, but I don't know where in my input file. How can I find that out?

Comment: The `log` files lists which files are loaded.

Comment: The log file does not show that any file containing the string subfig is loaded.

Comment: Do you have some sort of template file? It is most likely, that `subfig` is loaded there. 

You can use the approach to prepare [Minimal working examples](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to find the cause.

Comment: If you're not explicitly loading `subfig` in your input document, it may still be required (unbeknownst to you) in the class file and/or in one of the packages you load. Strategy? Divide & conquer: place the following code before `\documentclass` in your input file: `\makeatletter
\newcommand\CheckIfSubfigLoaded{\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}{\@latex@warning{The subfig package has been loaded}}{}}
\makeatother`. Then call the `\CheckIfSubfigLoaded` somewhere in your preamble. If you get my warning, it means the package has been already been loaded. That way you can locate where `subfig` is called .

Comment: @Jubobs that was what I was looking for, thank you.